# Problem generating confidence intervals for spaMM model in R

Tags: r, model, confidence-interval

I'm using the fitme() function of the spaMM package to fit a beta regression model controlling for spatial autocorrelation as follows:

```
mod<-fitme(MeanPC~BBDay+Area+(1|Level)+Matern(1|X+Y), data=data, family=beta_resp())
```

the model fits fine and generates coefficients with summary() but when I try to use confint(mod, "BBDay") or any other fixed effect parameters I get the following error message:

```
Error in (function (control.HLfit, ranFix = NULL, HLmethod, predictor,  : 
  init$beta must have names matching those of the design matrix
```

I have checked the design matrix and variable names all match correctly, and it works fine with other example datasets e.g. wafer, so why am I getting this issue and how do I stop it?